# Qt static build with static mysql plugin confusion

Tags: mysql, qt, plugins, static

I have built a Qt application which uses the MySQL library, but I am confused by the documentation on *static* versus *shared* builds.

From the Qt documentation at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/deployment-windows.html it says:

> To deploy plugin-based applications we should use the shared library
>   approach.

And on http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/deployment.html, it says:

> Static linking results in a stand-alone executable. The advantage is
>   that you will only have a few files to deploy. The disadvantages are
>   that the executables are large and with no flexibility and that you
>   cannot deploy plugins.  To deploy plugin-based applications, you can
>   use the shared library approach.

But on http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/plugins-howto.html, it seems to say the opposite, giving directions on how to use static plugins:

> Plugins can be linked statically against your application. If you
>   build the static version of Qt, this is the only option for including
>   Qt's predefined plugins. Using static plugins makes the deployment
>   less error-prone, but has the disadvantage that no functionality from
>   plugins can be added without a complete rebuild and redistribution of
>   the application.  ...     To link statically against those plugins, you
>   need to use the Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN() macro in your application and you
>   need to add the required plugins to your build using QTPLUGIN.

I want to build the Qt libraries statically (for easy deployment) and then use the static MySQL plugin. To do this, I did NOT use the binary distrubtion for Windows. Instead, I've started with the source qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4
Is the following the correct way to do a static build so that i can use the static MySql plugin?

configure -static -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010 -no-qt3support -no-webkit -no-script -plugin-sql-mysql -I C:\MySQL\include -L C:\MySQL\lib

1. This should build the Qt libraries statically AND the static plugin to be linked at run-time, correct? I would NOT need to build the Mysql Plugin from source separately, correct?
2. If I was to subtitute "-qt-sql-mysql" for "-plugin-sql-mysql" in above, it would include the MySQL driver directly in the QT static libraries, in which case I would NOT need to use the plugin at all, correct?

Thanks for making me unconfused!

Comment: The help clearly states that you shouldn't use the option `-debug-and-release` on any other platform than Mac OSX.

Answer (score 2):

The page of your second quote should really state:

> Static linking results in a stand-alone executable. The advantage is that you will only have a few files to deploy. The disadvantages are that the executables are large and with no flexibility and that you cannot deploy plugins. 
>   To deploy plugin-based applications, you can use the shared library approach **instead**.

You are right about both assumptions you made towards the end. For example, the configuration of our qt version includes

```
-plugin-sql-oci -qt-sql-sqlite
```

and the plugins\sqldrivers directory only shows the qsqloci(d).lib but nothing sqlite related.